# How do I get the time in this format in android?

Tags: android, time

I am trying to get the present time in this format in an android app. `time= "05:09pm 08/02/2011"` Right now I am using `Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance()` and `c.getTime()` to get the time and its coming out as `Tue Aug 23 02:34:25 PDT 2011`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`DateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html) Class
Something like this will get you the current time in the format you desire.

```
DateFormat.format("hh:mmaa dd/MM/yyyy", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: Hi, I tried what you did and Im getting this "time":"20:09PM 23\/08\/2011. Can you explain why I'm getting \/?

Comment: You might need to tell escape them by enclosing them in single quotes... eg. `hh:mmaa dd'/'MM'/'yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that in Android. You can use the [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)  wich is a class for formatting and parsing dates. Formatting turns a Date into a String, and parsing turns a String into a Date. Or you can the class [Formatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html) wich is low level but managing the localization is your responsibility.

You may find source code example on the Android javadoc on those classes

Answer (score 1):

Use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Format should be like

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "HH:mma dd/MM/yyyy" );
sdf.format( yourDate );
```

Regards,
 Stéphane